# Is there a proper Flutter way to show different layouts/screens/sections if its a user vs admin?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

- I will have a different menu/bottom navigation and pages for users and admins
- Wondering if there is a way to handle all of this or if its better to just make 2 apps (which I don't want to do)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a bool flag like `isAdmin` and build diffrent bottom navigation depending on it's flag